# Can't catch my IP Camera stream URL but other IP Camera stream URLs works

Tags: c#, url, emgucv, ip-camera

I am using the below code successfully to stream the URL of a public IP web camera.

Now, I have set up my own IP Camera and I am now trying to catch this feed but are not successfull.
I am not sure if I should share the correct URL because it can be overload if everyone is checking.

However, - the exact format of the URL is this which works in Chrome where I can see the feed:
**http://admin:admin@79.123.101.121:1024/web/admin.html** (not the real IP)

The feed in chrome looks like this which is the IP Camera software
[image]

I am then trying to catch ONLY the image stream itself with below code which I am not successful with. I have tried below with no success at all. Nothing appears in the image control:
http://admin:admin@79.123.101.121:1024/web/admin.html
http://admin:admin@79.123.101.121:1024
http://79.123.101.121:1024

As seen I add username and password which are: admin and admin which is needed to see the stream.

What could be the problem for this?

*(I am using the library: "Emgu.CV" version v4.1.1.3497 which exist in the Nuget that can be installed)*

```
        using Emgu.CV;
        using Emgu.CV.UI;
        using Emgu.CV.Structure;


        private VideoCapture _capture = null;
        private bool _captureInProgress;
        Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox imageBox = new Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            imageBox.Width = 700;
            imageBox.Height = 500;
            panel19.Controls.Add(imageBox);
            CvInvoke.UseOpenCL = false;
            try
            {
                _capture = new VideoCapture("http://77.243.103.105:8081/mjpg/video.mjpg");
                _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException excpt) { MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message); }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_capture == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _capture = new VideoCapture();
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException excpt) { MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message); }
            }
            if (_capture != null)
            {
                if (_captureInProgress)
                {
                    button1.Text = "Start!"; //if camera is getting frames then stop the capture and set button Text "Start" for resuming capture
                    Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
                }
                else
                {
                    button1.Text = "Stop"; //if camera is NOT getting frames then start the capture and set button Text to "Stop" for pausing capture
                    Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
                }
                _captureInProgress = !_captureInProgress;
            }
        }

        Mat frame = new Mat();
        private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
        {
            //_capture.Retrieve(frame, 0); //(1st try)
            _capture.Read(frame);  //This calls Grab() as grabbing a frame and then Retrieve(); (2nd try)
            imageBox.Image = frame;  //line 2
        }
```

**EDIT:**
I used wireshark when I entered the IP Camera in Chrome browser to sniff what is going on. I have changed the IP in the below so not everyone is looking as I am developing on the camera:

This is the information I get:

```js
GET /web/cgi-bin/hi3510/param.cgi?cmd=getvencattr&-chn=11&cmd=getvencattr&-chn=12&cmd=getsetupflag&cmd=getaudioflag&cmd=getrtmpattr HTTP/1.1
Host: 79.129.110.182:1024
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://79.129.110.182:1024/web/mainpage.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: streamselect=1; cookmun=1; language0=1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Hipcam
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:text/html
Connection: close
Content-Length: 379
```

Then If I build an URL from above info like this:

```js
http://79.129.110.182:1024/web/cgi-bin/hi3510/param.cgi?cmd=getvencattr&-chn=11&cmd=getvencattr&-chn=12&cmd=getsetupflag&cmd=getaudioflag&cmd=getrtmpattr
```

I get this result in chrome which actually are the settings for the IP Camera:

```js
var bps_1="1536"; var fps_1="25"; var gop_1="50"; var brmode_1="1"; var imagegrade_1="4"; var width_1="1280"; var height_1="720"; var bps_2="448"; var fps_2="5"; var gop_2="50"; var brmode_2="1"; var imagegrade_2="2"; var width_2="640"; var height_2="352"; var name0="admin"; var password0="admin"; var authLevel0="15"; var audioflag="1"; var rtmpport="1935";
```

Comment: Best way is to use a sniffer like I said in previous posting.  When you connect a request is sent between your application (client) and device (server).  The options for the connection is in the headers of the first request.  You need to compare the header in Chrome with the headers in your c# application.  Then fix the c# so the headers match the Chrome settings.  The video application has options that are not being set correctly.

Comment: Thank you I will give wireshark a try I have heard about that name before also. I will have a look to see if I can understand and see the headers as you mention. It seems like a good way to start at.

Comment: I was not sure what you ment with: "The video application has options that are not being set correctly" ?

Comment: The `username:password` part of the URL is artificial and is interpreted by your browser into a HTTP Authentication Header. In the actual web request you should format this accordingly. Wireshark is a great way to see what is actually going on. Just remember to change the credentials after you get it working ;)

Comment: Yes wireshark seems interesting. This will be the first time I use it, so I will see what I can understand from it ;) I will start now then :)

Comment: You are using a class to perform the connection and capture.  The class has properties that may need to be set to work with your browser settings.

Comment: "The video application has options that are not being set correctly" - you are not including certain required HTTP headers is what this means. If it works in the browser, then Wireshark will be revealing. Or you could use your browser's developer tools to capture the successful request.

Comment: All this is very interesting. I will dig into this deeply now to see what is going on. So I should probably include the appropriate headers along with the class/request for the URL as I can understand.

Comment: I used wireshark and could example get this info from Chrome. But I don't know how to understand this info? `[Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:tcp], [Coloring Rule Name: TCP SYN/FIN], [Coloring Rule String: tcp.flags & 0x02 || tcp.flags.fin == 1], Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 79.129.110.182, Dst: 192.168.42.179 (.... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)), .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0), Protocol: TCP (6), Source: 79.129.110.182, Destination: 192.168.42.179, Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 1935, Dst Port: 13902, Seq: 0, Ack: 1,Len: 0`

Comment: I have EDIT my original post with relevant information from wireshark. But I am not sure how to know, how to build the correct Stream URL for this to work?

Comment: Can you post both the wireshark results from chrome and you c# app.  I can explain everything. I Looked at all you postings and we are back to where I asked days ago to compare wireshark results.  Changing just the URL will not solve issue.  You need to modify the headers in the request.

Answer (score 0):

For newer cameras, try the following to get a stream:

- rtsp://default:@192.168.xx.xx:554/11
- http://default:@192.168.xx.xx/livestream.cgi?stream=2&action=play&media=video_audio_data

You can also make your own webpage and add a video canvas object, pass it as a parameter to libede265.js (found on camera, http://<your_ip>/js/libde265.js).

```
I'm also making a chrome extension to make this web interface better. Right now it's just fullscreen video and PTZ control via keyboard. Lots more to come.

I call it - "POS IP Cam" 
<head>
   <script src="<ip>/js/libde265.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
       let ip = "<your_ip>";
       let httpport = "80";
       let stream = 11; //11 or 12
       let username = "<your_username>";
       let password = "<your_password>";

       let video_canvas = document.getElementById("video_canvas");
       player = new libde265.RawPlayer(video_canvas);
       player.playvideo(ip, httpport, stream, username, password);
     });


   </script>

</head>

<body>

 <canvas id="video_canvas"></canvas>


</body>
```